# Most efficent way to retrieve certain rows in PHP and MS SQL based on specific conditions

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a project that I am working on at work and I need to know certain times everyday with the given data and conditions. Our company processes items and makes a datetime stamp for every single one in the format of 2015-09-16 07:15:18.000. They also have another column where they mention the day of week it is to be processed. In this case it would be Wednesday. This information is stored in the DB as "SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA". In the middle of the day they may decide to mark things in but stop production unless it was in before this time. This is called a cut off. So anything marked in after cut off will now use the next day of the week in the column. So if cut off is at 12:35:05 then 2015-09-16 15:04:11.000 is now stored as "TH" even though it was marked in on a Wednesday.

Historically they have never saved the cut off time in the database. Now they need to figure it for everyday since Jan 01, 2015. So I need to be able to return about 313 rows (we don't have data for Sundays) where the greatest time stamp for the day matches the day of column and return those results in PHP. But if someone can do this in pure transact SQL that will work for me as well.

I have been having a rough time making this happen and I would appreciate getting these results from this given data.

A sample of returned results would look like this:

```
Date_In                   Week_Day
-----------------------   --------
2015-01-01 12:15:18.000   TH
2015-01-02 12:13:23.000   FR
2015-01-03 12:45:56.000   SA
2015-01-05 12:09:11.000   MO
2015-01-06 11:54:49.000   TU
2015-01-07 12:14:30.000   WE
2015-01-08 12:15:28.000   TH
2015-01-09 12:05:11.000   FR
2015-01-10 12:53:58.000   SA
2015-01-12 12:01:12.000   MO
ect..
```

Comment: If I read this correctly, you want a Query that selects rows that have a Time greater than the 'cut-off' time, and those should have the `Week_Day` column updated to the next day?

Comment: It would actually be less than the cut off time. As the time after could be hours after cut off and wouldn't accurately represent when cut off took place.

Comment: @BradMetcalf in the example you gave, the cut-off would be 12:35:05.000. Given the example data, that would all rows but 2, right? We're ignoring those 2 (`2015-01-03 12:45:56.000   SA` and `2015-01-10 12:53:58.000   SA`) right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, pure tsql. `Substring` with `datename`.

```
select substring(datename(dw,convert(date,'2015-01-01 12:15:18.000')),0,3) -- returns 'TH'

--get records where date matches weekday
select * from mytable where substring(datename(dw,convert(date,Date_In)),0,3) = Week_Day
```

And something like this should give you results where the max date matches the weekday

```js
create table #test(
Date_In datetime,
Week_Day varchar(2)
)

insert into #test(Date_In,Week_Day) values ('2015-01-01 12:15:18.000','TH'),
('2015-01-02 12:13:23.000','FR'),
('2015-01-03 12:45:56.000','SA'),
('2015-01-05 12:09:11.000','MO'),
('2015-01-06 11:54:49.000','TU'),
('2015-01-07 12:00:30.000','TU'),
('2015-01-07 12:14:30.000','WE'),
('2015-01-08 12:15:28.000','TH'),
('2015-01-09 12:05:11.000','FR'),
('2015-01-10 12:53:58.000','SA'),
('2015-01-12 12:01:12.000','MO')
   
SELECT Max(Cast(#test.date_in AS DATE)) AS Date_In, 
       Max(#test.week_day)              AS Week_day 
FROM   #test 
       LEFT JOIN #test b 
              ON b.week_day = #test.week_day 
                 AND Cast(b.date_in AS DATE) = Cast(#test.date_in AS DATE) 
WHERE  Substring(Datename(dw, CONVERT(DATE, Cast(#test.date_in AS DATE))), 0, 3) 
       = 
       #test.week_day 
GROUP  BY Cast(#test.date_in AS DATE)
```

Comment: This would just return all rows wouldn't it?

Comment: @ZLK No there are 3 queries each working off the others result set. first we group the table and get the highest date, then we trim that down to only have the days where the max date matches the weekday and then finally we use those days as reference to get the rest of the data. Its not guaranteed to copy and paste but its the best I can do without a fiddle.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It returns 36,000ish rows out of 85,000ish rows in the table. The solution shouldn't exceed no more than 313 results.

Comment: @BradMetcalf I just setup a local example with an actual test case and revised the query have a look at my updated answer with a temp table

Comment: @kurt, The problem with your first query is that you were telling it to select everything whose date matched anything with a maximum date, which happened because you were casting it to a date. The updated query is fine, except that in the select statement, you shouldn't be converting it to a date and the left join isn't doing anything.

Comment: @ZLK Thanks I realised that as soon as I set up an example. The left join is actually doing something, it just looks like its not because the sample data is so small. The left join brings in the rest of the matching data otherwise you would only have one record per day.

Comment: @kurt, Your where condition filters the data for you such that you don't need a left join. The left join isn't doing anything because you're not filtering based on it, or selecting from it.

Comment: This works now and worked in 00:00:01 seconds so it is by far the most efficient. Thank you.

Comment: I did have to set the select as a DATETIME and add ORDER BY Date_In ASC to the query but otherwise this met all the requirements. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This should produce the desired result.

```
; WITH T AS (SELECT [Date_In], [Week_Day], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date_In]) RN
    FROM table)
SELECT C1.[Date_In], C1.[Week_Day]
FROM T C1
LEFT JOIN T C2 ON C2.RN -1 = C1.RN
WHERE C1.[Week_Day] <> C2.[Week_Day] OR C1.RN = (SELECT MAX(RN) FROM T)
ORDER BY C1.[Date_In]
```

Comment: This works. It returns 299 results for this unfinished year. And the results match my manual check. The only problem is it took 4 minutes and 29 seconds. So while it won't work in real time I can take the results and put them in another table to do what I have to do. If no one can do it more efficiently I will mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: If your table is large it will do that, you could reduce the time it takes by selecting only columns that you need to select. For example, the edit should be faster (but if you're going over thousands and thousands of rows it might still be slow).

Comment: @AlexanderMP, I would generally try to avoid cursors wherever possible. They're going to be a lot slower than basically anything else that could produce the required result.

Comment: @BradMetcalf I would suggest using kurt's query since mine is a make-shift one where I didn't realise the size of your table. Kurt's updated query would work a lot better for a larger table size.

Comment: Not in this case they won't. With a cursor you're only parsing once. With CTE, you're executing them twice, and performing a costly join. I bet a CTE would finish much faster. 4 minutes is an indicator of a complexity far greater than O(n), which would be a cursor.

Comment: You could be right. Like I said, mine is a make-shift query that didn't take into account the size of the table and is less efficient than the answers you and kurt provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of selecting the maximum value for that datetime for every day and every marked week day, as long as the date has the same week day as the marked day.

```
SELECT max(date_in), week_day FROM table
WHERE SUBSTRING (datename(dw, date_in), 1, 2) = week_day
GROUP BY Week_Day, CONVERT(date, date_in)
```

I can't properly test it, but this should work. Maybe a syntax error or something. Let me know if you try it.